# Extract all text from html after a specific tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text of an HTML file after the second occurrence of a specific tag.

I already tried regex and bs4, but I can't figure out what is going wrong. Regex always gives me only the hit itself without the rest of the html file and bs4 just does not work, because I don't know how to specify the end of the file for.

Simplified:

```html
<html>
    <veryspecific tag>
       abc
    </veryspecific tag>

    <stuff that comes before>
    </stuff that comes before>
    <...

       <veryspecific tag>
       abc
       </veryspecific tag>

       <other tags that come after>
       something
       </other tags that come after>
    </...>

    <other tags that come after2>
    something
    </other tags that come after2>
</html>
```

```py
#I tried splitting it, so I can take the last part which should contain the end of the file, starting from the latest occurrence, but it did not work:

htmltxt.split(r'abc.*$')


# I also tried to get the last tag and try to "while" over the 2 to get the text:

last_tag = html_parsed.findall('a')[-1]

while specific_tag != last_tag:
   text = ...
   specific_tag = specific_tag.next
```

I find the desired tag and can extract it, but I also need the rest of the file. Is there an easy and pythonic way to do it?

Comment: you probably don't want to do that with regex.  I would suggest that you consider a solution that includes xpath.  it would allow you to get at the info fairly easily.  here is a package that might be of use:  https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: So you want `<other tags that come after>` and the stuff after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
mark = soup.find('veryspecific').find_next('veryspecific')
all_other_tags = mark.find_all_next(name=True)

print(''.join(i.text for i in all_other_tags))
```

It gives me this output:

```
       something

    something
```